# Specific Cell Value Determines Column Colors Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

The code below works so if a user puts in a number value between 1-5 in the score section, a certain column / group of columns will change colors. If the Score is anything besides a 1,2,3,4 or 5 then no fill will happen on the columns.

[image]

Say a user puts in a value of 3 for question 2, the columns "Two", "Three", and "Five" will be highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Now, if the user puts in a value of 1 for Question One, the Columns "One", "Two" and "Three" will be highlighted in red. Column "Five" will still remain yellow, but "Two" and "Three" (Since there grouping overlaps with the questions) change to red because it was the most recent event.

[image]

I cant seem to figure out a way to make it so that the Score number determines if the current cells highlighted get changed to a different color. I want it so if a user puts in a value of 3 for question 2, the columns "Two", "Three", and "Five" will be highlighted in yellow, but if they then put in a value of 1 for Question One, the Column "One" will be highlighted in red and "Two" and "Three" should stay yellow because the score 3 is higher than 1.

[image]

Question One is grouped with columns: One,Two,Three

Question Two is grouped with columns: Two,Three,Five

Question Three is grouped with columns: Three,Four

Question Four is grouped with columns: Three,Four

Question Five is grouped with columns: One,Two,Three

Score 1 Displays: red

Score 2 Displays: orange

Score 3 Displays: yellow

Score 4 Displays: light green

Score 5 Displays: dark green

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D19")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("D19").Value
            Case 1
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case 2
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            Case 3
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Case 4
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Case 5
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
            Case Else
            Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End Select
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D20")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("D20").Value
            Case 1
                Range("M3:N28,P3:P28").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case 2
                Range("M3:N28,P3:P28").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            Case 3
                Range("M3:N28,P3:P28").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Case 4
                Range("M3:N28,P3:P28").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Case 5
                Range("M3:N28,P3:P28").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
            Case Else
            Range("M3:N28,P3:P28").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End Select
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D21")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("D21").Value
            Case 1
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case 2
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            Case 3
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Case 4
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Case 5
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
            Case Else
            Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End Select
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D22")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("D22").Value
            Case 1
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case 2
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            Case 3
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Case 4
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Case 5
                Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
            Case Else
            Range("N3:O28").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End Select
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D23")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("D23").Value
            Case 1
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case 2
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            Case 3
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Case 4
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Case 5
                Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
            Case Else
            Range("L3:N28").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope I am explaining myself properly. Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: Did you just repost this question? I feel like I saw this question earlier!? >,<

Comment: @CallumDA - here? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688761/cell-values-determines-column-color-vba

Comment: @CallumDA Couldn't figure out how to do it with conditional formatting either (not very experienced w/ excel or vba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (solution without VBA):

I used helper columns for this solution, although you could just hardcode everything into the formula and avoid the helper columns if you really wanted to, just makes the formula super long.

**EDIT** - *Just remembered that conditional formatting does not allow hardcoding, so actually helper cells are your only option in this case.*

I used this as the conditional formatting rule for red color in cell `K2`:

```
= MAX((MMULT((K$2=$B$2:$F$6)+0,(ROW($A$2:$A$6)>0)+0)*$I$2:$I$6))=1
```

The other conditional formatting rules are identical except for the last character. For example the rule for orange color would be `=2` at the end instead of `=1`.

The ranges are different than yours so you would have to change the ranges but the formula works. See a few examples below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to Excel, especially conditional formatting; so I'm a little confused on how to apply this.

Comment: Does the conditional formatting prioritize lowest numbers (Score) first? No matter what order you enter the data? If so then yes that's what I need. I tried doing what you did on a blank worksheet but couldn't get it to work, I kept getting errors so I don't think I was applying it properly.

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki In my example, click cell `K2`, click "Conditional Formatting" and then "New Rule". Then select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and paste the formula I have provided in this formula box. Then choose your desired formatting and click "OK". Repeat this for the 5 colors (formatting rules will be identical except last character as I explained in my post). Then just use format painter to apply the rule over whatever range you want.

Comment: I tried that before but its giving me the same error after I paste code and select my formatting. It says: "You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Conditional Formatting criteria."

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Ah, then I take back my statement: *"although you could just hardcode everything into the formula and avoid the helper columns if you really wanted to"*. I forgot that conditional formatting does not allow for hardcoded values, so you will have to use the helper cells as I have used in my example.

Comment: Once use the formula and set my format how do I use the helper cell?

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Just use it the exact way in my example. `= MAX((MMULT((K$2=$B$2:$F$6)+0,(ROW($A$2:$A$6)>0)+0)*$I$2:$I$6))=1`. And range `$A$2:$F$6` are my helper cells, but you can put them anywhere on the sheet that you want. Usually for helper cells I put them either way off to the right or way down and hide the rows/columns so that the helper cells are hidden.

Comment: I have my sheet structured like yours. All I have to do is paste that conditional formatting formula into K2 and chose a color? I tried doing that and it doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens when I enter the score values in.

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Yes, enter conditional formatting rule in cell `K2` and then use format painter to apply the formatting to the other cells `L2:O2`.

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Not sure what to tell you. It is working for me, as evidenced by the screenshots. Perhaps look up conditional formatting tutorials to ensure you are doing everything right. Can you mark my answer as correct please?

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki I suppose you could replace `K$2` in the formula with `INDEX($A$2:$A$6,COLUMN(K$2)-COLUMN($K$2)+1)`. This just grabs the `One`, `Two`, etc. from the `A2:A6` range rather than `K2:O2` range, so the formula should now work regardless of what is in the cells `K2:O2`.

Comment: What If I wanted all texts in the columns the same. Instead of One Two Three Four and Five. The formula doesn't work if all the text is the same, but I need everything to say "x" like in the above pictures.

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Did you read my previous comment? Altering the formula to that will no longer look up the value in the column headers, but instead in the helper cells, so you should be able to put whatever you want in the column headers without affecting anything.

Comment: Oh okay I see what you mean. Are you saying the formula should look like this: 
`= MAX((MMULT((INDEX($A$2:$A$6,COLUMN(K$2)-COLUMN($K$2)+1)=$B$16:$F$20)+0,(ROW($A$13:$A$17)>0)+0)*$J$13:$J$17))=1`

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Well, looks like you have your helper cells moved from where I originally had them. This is OK but just means that you will have to update the formula accordingly. E.g. `$A$2:$A$6` needs to be changed to `$A$16:$A$20`. This is just a guess based on your formula referencing `$B$16:$F$20` instead of `$B$2:$F$6`.

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki Based on this information, your formula should be `= MAX((MMULT((INDEX($A$19:$A$23,COLUMN(L$3)-COLUMN($L$3)+1)=$F$41:$J$45)+0,(ROW($A$19:$A$23)>0)+0)*$D$19:$D$23))=1`. By the way, this discussion right now is discussing an absolutely trivial problem that you shouldn't need my help to fix...

Answer (score 2):

The code bellow compares all possible combinations of the answers regardless of their sequence

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Const U1 = 19    'User input row 1
    Const U2 = 20
    Const U3 = 21
    Const U4 = 22
    Const U5 = 23
    Const D = 4      'User input column

    Dim r As Long, v As Long, fnd As Range
    r = Target.Row
    v = Val(Target.Value2)

    With Target.Parent

        Set fnd = .UsedRange.Find("One")    'find first question
        If Target.Column <> D Or r < U1 Or r > U5 Or v > 5 Or fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Dim fr As Long, lr As Long, fc As Long
        fr = fnd.Row + 1                'first used row
        lr = .UsedRange.Rows.Count      'last used row
        fc = fnd.Column                 'last used column

        Dim a1 As Long, a2 As Long, a3 As Long, a4 As Long, a5 As Long
        a1 = Val(.Cells(U1, D).Value2)  'answer 1
        a2 = Val(.Cells(U2, D).Value2)
        a3 = Val(.Cells(U3, D).Value2)
        a4 = Val(.Cells(U4, D).Value2)
        a5 = Val(.Cells(U5, D).Value2)

        Dim c1 As Range, c2 As Range, c3 As Range, c4 As Range, c5 As Range
        Set c1 = .Range(.Cells(fr, fc + 0), .Cells(lr, fc + 0)) 'column 1
        Set c2 = .Range(.Cells(fr, fc + 1), .Cells(lr, fc + 1))
        Set c3 = .Range(.Cells(fr, fc + 2), .Cells(lr, fc + 2))
        Set c4 = .Range(.Cells(fr, fc + 3), .Cells(lr, fc + 3))
        Set c5 = .Range(.Cells(fr, fc + 4), .Cells(lr, fc + 4))

        Dim qCols As Range, clr As Long
        Select Case r
            Case U1
                Set qCols = Union(c1, c2, c3)   'question 1
                Select Case True
                    Case v < a3 Or v < a4:  Set qCols = Union(c1, c2)
                    Case v < a2:            Set qCols = c1
                End Select
            Case U2
                Set qCols = Union(c2, c3, c5)   'question 2
                Select Case True
                    Case v < a3 Or v < a4:  Set qCols = Union(c2, c5)
                    Case v < a1:            Set qCols = c5
                End Select
            Case U3
                Set qCols = Union(c3, c4)       'question 3
                Select Case True
                    Case v < a1 Or v < a2:  Set qCols = c4
                    Case v < a5:            Set qCols = c3
                End Select
            Case U4
                Set qCols = Union(c3, c4)       'question 4
                If v < a2 Or v < a5 Then Set qCols = c4
            Case U5
                Set qCols = Union(c1, c2, c3)   'question 5
                Select Case True
                    Case v < a3 Or v < a4:              Set qCols = Union(c1, c2)
                    Case v < a2 And (v < a3 Or v < a4): Set qCols = c1
                End Select
        End Select

        clr = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Select Case v   'set colors based on current cell's value
            Case 1: clr = RGB(255, 0, 0)    'red
            Case 2: clr = RGB(255, 111, 0)  'orange
            Case 3: clr = RGB(255, 255, 0)  'yellow
            Case 4: clr = RGB(0, 255, 0)    'light green
            Case 5: clr = RGB(0, 111, 0)    'dark green
        End Select

        If v < 1 Then
          .UsedRange.Interior.Pattern = xlNone  'if cell value <1 clear all colors
        Else
          If Not qCols Is Nothing Then qCols.Interior.Color = clr
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```